# FedEx API get rate error - Fault

Tags: web-services, api, fedex

Hi I am using FedEx API's to get the rates of a shipment from `Singapore` to `India`, I am passing the parameters as required by the API but it throws error and I am not able to understand what is causing the problem from stack trace :

```
00:42:36.372 [http-bio-8106-exec-3] ERROR com.ocr.logistics.ci.api.impl.FedexSoapSenderImpl - Error Occured while FEDEX Fetch Rates
org.apache.axis.AxisFault: Fault
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)]
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at com.fedex.rate.stub.RateServiceSoapBindingStub.getRates(RateServiceSoapBindingStub.java:2292) ~[fedex-client-library-rate.jar:?]
    at com.ocr.logistics.ci.api.impl.FedexSoapSenderImpl.fetchRates(FedexSoapSenderImpl.java:62) [logistics-processor-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.ocr.logistics.processor.impl.LogisticsProcessorImpl.fetchRates(LogisticsProcessorImpl.java:59) [logistics-processor-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.ocr.logistics.processor.impl.LogisticsProcessorImpl.fetchCombinedRates(LogisticsProcessorImpl.java:75) [logistics-processor-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.ocr.ead.global.action.LogisticsAction.getRates(LogisticsAction.java:676) [LogisticsAction.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:894) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1539) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1615) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431) [ognl-3.1.12.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:351) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:403) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:349) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:436) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.ocr.common.struts2.ActionAwareInterceptor.intercept(ActionAwareInterceptor.java:55) [global.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:139) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:69) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:248) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.ocr.common.struts2.PopulateEntityInterceptor.intercept(PopulateEntityInterceptor.java:108) [global.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143) [struts2-core-2.5.10.jar:2.5.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at com.xss.filter.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:117) [xssFilter.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at com.ocr.encode.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:122) [charEncodeFilter.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

This is the error message in debug mode :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because of the wrong input... i was sending the `null` for address line in fedex request object, after replace null to empty string it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lookout for null in address line especially addressLine2 or phone number.